# Tableview reload data reverts numbers to default value

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to present the data (in a cell) that a user inputed using a popup. I am able to retrieve the data from the popup, however, it reverts back to the original value when I bring up a different pop up.

**ViewController**

```
var highScore = "~"
var level = "1"

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let scorePopupViewController = segue.destination as? ScorePopupViewController{
            scorePopupViewController.onSaveScore = updateHighScore
        }else if let levelPopupViewController = segue.destination as? LevelViewController{
            levelPopupViewController.onSaveLevelMyKey = updateLevel
            levelPopupViewController.mode = sender as! Int
        }
    }


func updateHighScore(_ data:String?)->(){
        if data != nil{
            highScore = data!
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
func updateLevel(_ data:[String]?)->(){
        if data != nil{
             level = String(data![1])
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
//third section
if indexPath.section == 3{
            let statisticCell:StatisticTableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "STATS_CELL") as? StatisticTableViewCell
            statisticCell.delegate = self
            statisticCell.scoreSelectBtn.titleLabel?.text = self. highScore
            statisticCell.levelSelectBtn.titleLabel?.text = self.level    
            return statisticCell
}

//Delegate for cell
func scoreSelectBtnWasPressed() {
     performSegue(withIdentifier: "TO_SCOREPOPVC", sender: nil)
 }
    
func levelSelectBtnWasPressed() {
     performSegue(withIdentifier: "TO_LEVELPOPVC", sender: 0)
 }
```

**ScorePopupVC**

```
var onSaveScore:((_ data: String?)->())?

@IBAction func addScoreBtnWasPressed() {
        if scoreTextField.text! != ""{
            onSaveScore?(scoreTextField.text!)
        }else{
            onSaveScore?(nil)
        }
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }

@objc func dismissView (_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        
        if scoreTextField.text! == ""{
            onSaveScore?(nil)
        }
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
```

The weird part is that when I print highscore and level in the `cellForRowAt` I get the correct score. Its a little complicated so I created a diagram of what is happening. Any help is appreciated

[image]

Comment: cant reproduce can you add a gihub demo ?

Comment: Basically, the problem arises from the fact that tableView.reloadData() refreshes all cells of the tableView, hence the label is lost. If, for example, you encapsulated all UITableViewCell data into a structure, and then in cellForRow seed each cell with their corresponding structure, the state would then be refreshed correctly. Do you need a more detailed answer?

Comment: @obabovic Thank you for your answer. yes it would be great if there is a detailed answer.  `hence the label is lost` even though it is "lost" wouldn't it display the text since `highscore` and `level` are both global variables?

Comment: @Satsuki Oh, what is the type of the scoreSelectBtn and levelSelectBtn? Is it UIButton? If so, would you try setting their texts with setTitle() ? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624018-settitle

Comment: @obabovic OMG this did it .. unbelievable... THANK YOU!

Comment: Glad to help :) The problem is actually much less sinister than I thought at first!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should update the title of an UIButton with the [setTitle(title: String?, for: UIControl.State)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624018-settitle) function, instead of accessing the titleLabel directly. This way, the view is informed that the uibutton content needs an update.

Comment: To be exact, the complete function signature is `setTitle(title: String?, for: UIControl.State)`.
(Swift 5)

Comment: Done, please approve it.